# How is validation of neural nets implemented?

Tags: neural-networks, python, validation, keras

I know what are training, validation and testing stages. But, I want to know how validation is implemented. Let's consider the following data : data_train, data_val, data_test as respectively training, validation and test data. Let's suppose that the model is created with keras:

```
model = Sequential(...)
```

The validation stage occurs during the training stage:

```
for i in range(epochs):
    loss_train = my_function_computing_loss(model, data_train)
    # update weights and biases
    ...
    # Then try to validate
    my_validation_function(model, data_val)
```

In keras, when we let the model manage validation, we can see that

```
loss_train and loss_val are almost close (for good tuning).
```

What is the aspect of the code that makes loss_train and loss_val closer?

Comment: Yes It is not a programming problem. To get back to what you're saying, I agree that the model doesn't know anything about validation data. But in keras, when at a given 'epoch' the training is not well tuned, we have the impression that keras will manage so that the two losses are close. And it's how keras manages to do it that I'm trying to understand (unfortunately I don't have access to the source code).

Comment: All keras wants is a low training loss. That's literally the only thing it cares about. It doesn't look at the validation loss — it just reports it so that you can see what's going on. In other words, it does not update model parameters using the validation error.

Comment: Ah okay, I get it. Basically, the valiation data is only there to assess the predictive performance of the model after each 'epoch', the rest is up to us to manage and interpret. thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validation data should not be influencing the training process. The validation data is used to a "sanity check" of the model, and for us to check for overfitting or undefitting.

So for example, if you have a overfitted model, the training accuracy will be really high, because the model "memorized" the data, and the validation accuracy will be significantly lower or it will stay constant regardless of the training steps.

If the training processes is going well, test and validation loss should be close and with a similar behavior.

Comment: Your answer and those of @kwinkunks allowed me to understand very well what it is.